# Protect / Encode Objective C code

Tags: objective-c, obfuscation

i need a way to turn Objective-C code into some encoded code soup, so it would be very very hard to modify anything

i was thinking about some macro and variable encoder, but didnt found any tool for that

(its an XCode project for an iPhone app)

thank you

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need to do that? Maybe you can just compile your code and if you need to share it, do it as a Objective-C library...

Comment: based on an agreement i have to provide the source code, i dont want to go into detail about this, but i dont want to make it so easy for them

Comment: @Peter Lapisu: " i have to provide the source code".  Just provide it, and save yourself the cost of hiring a lawyer in the future.

Comment: Sounds like you made the wrong agreement. Otherwise, compile it into assembly (gcc -S) and supply that, since it is also "source code".

Comment: @Peter: What you could try to do, is abstract part of your code to a library and claim it to be your personal framework/toolbox which you developed in the past, for which the client didn't pay to have the source.

Comment: @Peter Lapisu: You're in a tough spot. Look for some C obfuscators. You might have more luck with C obfuscators than with Objective-C obfuscators. Sorry my answer is not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Peter: elaborating on my previous comment, the client will probably not notice that part of the source code is simply not there, until they need to develop further, at which point you probably got paid long ago and you're in a good position to negotiate.

Comment: You signed an agreement to provide source, and now you want to weasel out of it by providing it in a form that isn't useful? That's pretty low.

Comment: @Peter Lapisu If you think there's nothing they can argue about, you don't know much about lawyers. And there's reason to think that your obfuscated "source code" may not pass muster. For example, the GPL says: "The “source code” for a work means the preferred form of the work for making modifications to it." I understand that you're not working under the GPL, but you should expect the other side to bring that up as evidence of a commonly accepted definition of _source code_. Save your time and money -- do what you agreed to do.